# Почему не снимается роль?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть бот в дискорде. Если убрать эмодзи, а то есть реакцию - должна убраться роль, но вместо этого я получаю:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

Не знаю, как можно обойти данную ошибку

Код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)

    if payload.message_id == 969645670610907146 and reaction.emoji == '':
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=968944234046562424)
        await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во первых нужно использовать не on_raw_reaction_add, а on_raw_reaction_remove. А во вторых (по непонятной причине) payload.member возвращает None из за чего приходится доставать объект пользователя вручную. Как-то так:

```
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent) -> None:
    roles = {"": "the_best_role"}
    message_id = id_сообщения
    role_name = roles.get(payload.emoji.name)
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
    if role_name:
        if payload.message_id == message_id:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role_name)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```

При добавлении тоже самое, но заместо `remove_roles` нужен `add_roles`.