# Как вместо None получать имя пользователя?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Делаю дискорд-бота, который при выборе реакции, выдаёт роль, а при отмене реакции, забирает её.
При событии `on_raw_reaction_add` я получаю пользователя, который выбрал реакцию:

```
@bot.event

async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):
    member = reaction.member
```

И если вывести `member` на экран при помощи `print`, то получим:
Nickname#0001

А если сделать точно так же, но в событии `on_raw_reaction_remove`

```
@bot.event

async def on_raw_reaction_remove(reaction):
    member = reaction.member
```

И вывести `member`, то получим `None`

Из-за этого мой последующий код не работает. Как это исправить? Как вместо None получать имя пользователя?

Код:

```
@bot.event 
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(reaction):
    msg_id = reaction.message_id
    guild = bot.get_guild(9837*********4)
    emoji = str(reaction.emoji)
    member = reaction.member 

    role = utils.get(guild.roles, id = 98*******9)  

    if msg_id == 9*********6:
        if emoji == '':
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1405163/Почему-не-снимается-роль/1405187#1405187 
Если кратко, то `member = await guild.fetch_member(reaction.user_id)`. В `on_raw_reaction_remove` приходит не `discord.Reaction`, а `discord.RawReactionActionEvent`

Comment: Спасибо большое